# Preload pages using jQuery .load()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with a few popups showing the details of each item on the page. When the user clicks on a button, the popup (which is a jQuery dialog) is shown.  The html of the dialog is pulled from another page/url. I use jQuery's .load() method.  The browser takes a couple of seconds the first time a page is loaded into my dialog, something that my boss doesn't want.

I've tried to preload these pages asynchronously, but I can't get it to work.  The page gets blocked until all the loading happens. I've tried it three different ways:

```
//1
$('.transactions-preloader').each(
    function(index, Element){
    var id = Element.id.replace('details-dialog', '');
        $(this).load( "/" + id + "/1/" + period + ".html" );
    }
);

//2
$('.transactions-preloader').each(
    function(index, Element){
        var id = Element.id.replace('details-dialog', '');
        $.ajax({
              url: "/" + id + "/1/" + period + ".html",
              async: true,
              cache: false,
              success: function(html){
                  $("#"+Element.id).html(html);
              }
             });
    }
);

//3
$('.transactions-preloader').each(
    function(index, Element){
        var id = Element.id.replace('details-dialog', '');
        $.get( "/" + id + "/1/" + period + ".html", function(data) {
            $("#"+Element.id).html(data);
        });
    }
);
```

The three ways work fine, except that they all block the page while the load is happening.

Any ideas on how to do asynchronously preloading?

Comment: Seems like a bad idea to preload something this way, that's why I did it all through ajax instead of preloading the content... I'll just have to explain my boss this, unless you guys come with another idea.  I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will not hang the browser.

```
$('.transactions-preloader').each(
    function(index, Element){
    setTimeout(function(){
      var id = Element.id.replace('details-dialog', '');
          $(this).load( "/" + id + "/1/" + period + ".html" );
      }
   }, 10);
);
```

Comment: I tried your code, it looks like the ", 10);" should be one line up. Inspecting the network I noticed that the pages were loaded, but the html doesn't get inserted into the div. I tried changing "$(this).load(" for "$("#"+Element.id).load(" but the script still hangs the browser.
Any idea on what's going wrong? I need to be able to call "$("#"+Element.id).dialog(...)" on those elements

Answer (score 0):

If you know the paths of the files, a classic pre-loader script might be useful:

```
var loadImages = (function() {
  var imageArray = [];

  // imagePaths is an array of image paths
  return function(imagePaths) {
    var i = imagePaths.length;
    var image;

    while (i--) {
      image = new Image();
      image.src = imagePaths[i];
      imageArray.push(image);
    }
  }
}());
```

Whenever you load a new part of the page, pass the image paths in an array to the function. You can clear out the imageArray each time if you want, once the images are loaded they don't need to stay in the array, but they have to hang around long enough to be loaded.

Comment: I tried something similar, but I'm not preloading images, but entire pages (even though they are small)... I don't know if you could modify this code to work with a page instead of an image

Comment: I suppose you could create iFrames instead of images, otherwise much the same. Never seen it done though.

Comment: you probably haven't seen it because it's a bad idea... the users will use this function probably 1% of the time.... I'll just explain it to him.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(window).load(function() {
    // preloading code
    })
```

this will call the preload after your page (including all frames, images, etc) loaded.

note that this is jquery [load event handler](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/), not [load function](http://api.jquery.com/load/)